# Should I dispose injected variable after assigment

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ninject, ioc-container, dispose

I'm working on an active directory service class for my ASP.NET MVC web app. I use Ninject to IOC. I inject Forest to my class with the following manner.

```
private readonly Forest forest;
public ActiveDirectoryServices(Forest forest)
{
   this.forest = forest;
}
```

In my NinjectWebCommon I use the following binding.

```
kernel.Bind<Forest>().ToSelf().InRequestScope();
```

After that, in my function I assign a new Forest to my injected forest variable.

```
this.forest = Forest.GetCurrentForest();
```

I know that, ninject handle object disposing if I use InRequestScope() binding, but is it true after a new reference assigment as well?
My question is, should I dispose the forest field in my class, or Ninject will handle it?

Comment: the container will manage what it creates. If you create further instances after that, the container is unaware of those.

Comment: Thank you for your response. One more question. Can this cause memory leak? kernel.Bind<GlobalCatalog>().ToMethod(t => Forest.GetCurrentForest().FindGlobalCatalog());

Comment: You should share the code of `Forest.GetCurrentForest()` Is this a static method ? With a service locator call ?